# libz or/and libpng for Windows (Phone) 8 Apps

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-8, zlib, libpng, libz

The problem is pretty simple. When building for W(P)8 you can't compile .c files or use old C syntax code (the one where function parameters are specified twice).

Libpng is easily compilable under C++ as it doesn't use old synax code but libz isn't. I haven't been able to find a suitable replacement for libz that can compile for these environments.

I tried MiniZ which lacks (dunno why) definitions for functions like inflatereset, then I found no solution to loading pngs alternatively under Windows Phone 8 from native C++ code (you can use WIC on Windows 8 but the library doesn't exist for ARM builds).

There's also this : https://github.com/doo/ZIP-WinRT but it uses managed classes and is only useful if you want to extract zip files. Previous libz dependent code won't compile and I need it for libpng to compile basically.

Please do not comment if you don't know what these flags mean

"Windows Store App support"

"Consume Windows runtime extension"

Answer (score 0):

The "OF(args)" macro in zconf.h writes the extra set of function parameters.  You should be able to get rid of them by defining the macro OF(args) to ().  You could send the definition in via your compile command, your makefile or whatever, or you could manually edit zconf.h and put

```
#define OF(args)  ()
```

right before

```
#ifndef OF /* function prototypes */
```